# Separate elements in a list python 3 without [] or (), without new line

Tags: python, bash, rsync

I need to  pass options to rsync. I do that with

```
EXCLUDE = [".svn",".dropbox"]
OPTS = "-rltgoi --delay-updates --delete --exclude={:} --chmod=a-w".format(EXCLUDE)
```

this code prints

```
-rltgoi --delay-updates --delete --exclude=['.svn', '.dropbox'] --chmod=a-w
```

`[]` can't be processed by the shell

I need to pass

```
-rltgoi --delay-updates --delete --exclude=.svn,.dropbox --chmod=a-w
```

Comment: `",".join(EXCLUDE)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to join `EXCLUDE` into a comma-separated string:

```
EXCLUDE = ','.join(EXCLUDE)
```

You are instead interpolating the list representation, which is not what you want here (note that a list representation includes *quoted* string values as well).

Answer (score 1):

You should join the excludes into a string before you add them to the command.

```
OPTS = "-rltgoi --delay-updates --delete --exclude={0} --chmod=a-w".format(",".join(EXCLUDE))
```